# PostgreSQL window function: serial # of event by day among many days

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have this table with just one column of type datetime. And I have many events per day.

To get all the events it is just SELECT date FROM table;

How can I add a serial number to each row so that the first row in each day is 1, the second is 2, and so on, reseting the serial count on the next day?

I am looking for a solution using PostgreSQL window functions.

Comment: Please add some sample data and  the expected output based on that data (_formatted_ text please, no screen shots)

Answer (score 0):

Create dummy date first (should haven been part of question):

```
CREATE TABLE "table"
(
  date timestamp with time zone
);

insert into "table"(date)
select now()+(x*23||'minutes')::interval
from generate_series(1, 100) as x;
```

Then query all rows including a counter:

```
select date, row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('day', date))
from "table"
```